# Inno Setup Detect (get notified) when WizardForm minimizes and restores

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am in the process of adding a BASS Audio Project in my Pascal Script. Adding a music playback for a very long installation is not bad for the user. But it is good to stop the music when user minimizes the `WizardForm` to taskbar. And automatically start music if user restores it again from taskbar.

I like to know how can I detect if `WizardForm` is minimized or restored and pause or start BASS music playing according to `WizardForm`'s window state. (Using functions like like `BASS_Pause`,`BASS_Stop` or `BASS_Start.`)

How and what should I choose to do this? `TWindowState` or `WMSYSCOMMAND?`

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there's any event that will notify you when the wizard form is minimized or restored. The `TForm.WindowState` is not available in the Inno Setup Pascal Script either.

---

But you can schedule a frequent timer and check for changes in the form state.

Note the the form is actually hidden, not minimized, when you click the minimize button (there's no minimize animation). So use the [`GetWindowLong` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongw) to check for the `WS_VISIBLE` window style.

```pascal
[Code]

const
  GWL_STYLE = -16; 
  WS_VISIBLE = $10000000;

function GetWindowLong(hWnd: THandle; nIndex: Integer): LongInt;
  external 'GetWindowLongW@User32.dll stdcall';
function SetTimer(
  hWnd: longword; nIDEvent, uElapse: LongWord; lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  WasHidden: Boolean;

procedure HiddenTimerProc(H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
var
  Hidden: Boolean;
  Style: LongInt;
begin
  Style := GetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
  Hidden := (Style and WS_VISIBLE) = 0;
  if Hidden and not WasHidden then
  begin
    Log('Minimized, stopping music...');
  end
    else
  if not Hidden and WasHidden then
  begin
    Log('Restored, resuming music...');
  end;
  WasHidden := Hidden;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WasHidden := False;
  SetTimer(0, 0, 500, CreateCallback(@HiddenTimerProc));
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no any Notify Event that can inform you if WizardForm is Minimized or Restored because such Event is not necessary to build Installations.

**If you Really want to check if WizardForm is Restored or Minimized (Not to check its Visibility),**

---

**First you need to modify Inno Setup Source Code to give Minimize and Restore Transitions (Animations) for Wizard Window.**

*Note: the following Source Code Changes are successfully tested with Inno Setup 5.5.9 Unicode and Ansi Versions.*

1. Hiding Hidden Application Form of Delphi from Inno Setup's Setup Program completely:

   *Setup.exe > Project Options for Setup.exe > Application > Target File Extension > e32.*

   *Right Click Setup.e32 > View Source.*

   *Change the `{ Initialize ...` Section of Setup Program like this:*

   *Add* `if shWindowVisible in SetupHeader.Options then` *before the line* `ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_SHOW);`*.*

   *Change the `{ Run }` Section of Setup Program like this:*

   ```pascal
   ...
   { Run }
   try
     Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := False;
     Application.ShowMainForm := False;
     ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
     Application.Run;
   except
   ...
   ```

   *You're done! Now it will be hidden.*

   For a background information, see [Setup Programs created using Inno Setup Compiler doesn't display Minimize Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38411126/850848).
2. Adding Minimize and Restore Transitions (Animations) to Inno Setup Wizard Form:

   *In Unit Wizard,*

   *Change* `TWizardForm.CreateParams` *like this:*

   ```pascal
   procedure TWizardForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
   begin
     inherited;
     { Ensure the form is on top of MainForm by making MainForm
       the "parent" of the form when *MainForm is set to Visible*. }
     if shWindowVisible in SetupHeader.Options then
       Params.WndParent := MainForm.Handle
     else
       Params.WndParent := GetDesktopWindow;
   end;
   ```

   *Change* `TWizardForm.WMSysCommand` *like this:*

   ```pascal
   procedure TWizardForm.WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand);
   begin
     if Message.CmdType and $FFF0 = SC_MINIMIZE then begin
       { A minimize button is shown on the wizard form when (shWindowVisible in
         SetupHeader.Options). When it is clicked we want to minimize the whole
         application. }
       if shWindowVisible in SetupHeader.Options then
         Application.Minimize
       else
         ShowWindow(WizardForm.Handle, SW_MINIMIZE);
     end
     else
     if Message.CmdType and $FFF0 = SC_RESTORE then begin
       if shWindowVisible in SetupHeader.Options then
         Application.Restore
       else
         ShowWindow(WizardForm.Handle, SW_RESTORE);
     end;
     if Message.CmdType = 9999 then
       MainForm.ShowAboutBox
     else
       inherited;
   end;
   ```

   *Declare a new procedure called* `TWizardForm.FormShow` *like shown below:*

   ```pascal
   procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
   ```

   *Declare it like below in `Implementation` Section of Unit Wizard.*

   ```pascal
   procedure TWizardForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if not(shWindowVisible in SetupHeader.Options) then
       ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
   end;
   ```

   *Finally, add this `TWizardForm.FormShow` as OnShow Form Event of the WizardForm.*

   *You're almost done! Now Wizard Window should display Restore and Minimize Animations as you expect.*
3. Fixing MessageBox Parent Window issue after adding Minimize Transitions (Animations) to the Inno Setup Wizard:

   *Note: This must be done to prevent Logged Wizard Message Boxes (Whose can be logged with Inno Setup Compiler Log) from sometimes displaying two Taskbar Buttons even WizardForm is Visible.*

   *In the Section `{ Variables for command line parameters }` of Unit Main, declare a new Boolean Variable like this:*

   ```pascal
   IsApplicationRunning: Boolean;
   ```

   *In Unit Main,*

   *Change the procedure* `AbortInit` *like this:*

   ```pascal
   procedure AbortInit(const Msg: TSetupMessageID);
   begin
     IsApplicationRunning := False;
     LoggedMsgBox(SetupMessages[Msg], '', mbCriticalError, MB_OK, True, IDOK);
     Abort;
   end;
   ```

   *Change the procedure* `AbortInitFmt1` *like this:*

   ```pascal
   procedure AbortInitFmt1(const Msg: TSetupMessageID; const Arg1: String);
   begin
     IsApplicationRunning := False;
     LoggedMsgBox(FmtSetupMessage(Msg, [Arg1]), '', mbCriticalError, MB_OK, True, IDOK);
     Abort;
   end;
   ```

   *Change the procedure* `AbortInitServicePackRequired` *like this:*

   ```pascal
   procedure AbortInitServicePackRequired(const ServicePack: Word);
   begin
     IsApplicationRunning := False;
     LoggedMsgBox(FmtSetupMessage(msgWindowsServicePackRequired, ['Windows', IntToStr(Hi(ServicePack))]), '', mbCriticalError, MB_OK, True, IDOK);
     Abort;
   end;
   ```

   *In Unit Wizard,*

   *Modify the previously added procedure* `TWizardForm.FormShow` *like this:*

   ```pascal
   procedure TWizardForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if not(shWindowVisible in SetupHeader.Options) then
       ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
     IsApplicationRunning := True;
   end;
   ```

   *In Unit CmnFunc,*

   *Add `Wizard` and `Main` to the Uses Section in `Implementation` of Unit CmnFunc.*

   *Change the procedure* `AppMessageBox` *like this:*

   ```pascal
   function AppMessageBox(const Text, Caption: PChar; Flags: Longint): Integer;
   var
     ActiveWindow: HWND;
     MessageHandler: HWND;
     WindowList: Pointer;
   {$IFNDEF IS_D4}
     DidMove: Boolean;
     OldRect: TRect;
   {$ENDIF}
   begin
     if MessageBoxRightToLeft then
       Flags := Flags or (MB_RTLREADING or MB_RIGHT);

     if IsApplicationRunning = False then
       MessageHandler := Application.Handle
     else
       MessageHandler := WizardForm.Handle;

     { If the application window isn't currently visible, show the message box
       with no owner window so it'll get a taskbar button }
     if IsIconic(MessageHandler) or (GetWindowLong(MessageHandler, GWL_STYLE) and WS_VISIBLE = 0) or (GetWindowLong(MessageHandler, GWL_EXSTYLE) and WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW <> 0) then begin
       ActiveWindow := GetActiveWindow;
       WindowList := DisableTaskWindows(0);
       try
         { Note: DisableTaskWindows doesn't disable invisible windows.
           MB_TASKMODAL will ensure that Application.Handle gets disabled too. }
         Result := MessageBox(0, Text, Caption, Flags or MB_TASKMODAL);
       finally
         EnableTaskWindows(WindowList);
         SetActiveWindow(ActiveWindow);
       end;
       Exit;
     end;

     TriggerMessageBoxCallbackFunc(Flags, False);
     try
       {$IFDEF IS_D4}
       { On Delphi 4+, simply call Application.MessageBox }
       Result := Application.MessageBox(Text, Caption, Flags);
       {$ELSE}
       { Use custom implementation on Delphi 2 and 3. The Flags parameter is
         incorrectly declared as a Word on Delphi 2's Application.MessageBox, and
         there is no support for multiple monitors. }
       DidMove := MoveAppWindowToActiveWindowMonitor(OldRect);
       try
         ActiveWindow := GetActiveWindow;
         WindowList := DisableTaskWindows(0);
         try
           Result := MessageBox(Application.Handle, Text, Caption, Flags);
         finally
           EnableTaskWindows(WindowList);
           SetActiveWindow(ActiveWindow);
         end;
       finally
         if DidMove then
           SetWindowPos(Application.Handle, 0,
             OldRect.Left + ((OldRect.Right - OldRect.Left) div 2),
             OldRect.Top + ((OldRect.Bottom - OldRect.Top) div 2),
             0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOREDRAW or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);
       end;
       {$ENDIF}
     finally
       TriggerMessageBoxCallbackFunc(Flags, True);
     end;
   end;
   ```

   *Now all Logged and any other Message Boxes will be displayed Normally!*

   Now, Compile the Setup Program (Setup.e32) using a Recommended Compiler in the ReadMe File and copy it to the directory where you installed Inno Setup.

   *Note: The installed version of Inno Setup Unicode or Ansi must match the Version of the source code of Inno Setup which you're modified to Re-compile. Or you can Compile whole Inno Setup Project and Copy - Replace this modified and Re-compiled Setup Program (Setup.e32) to the directory where you compiled Inno Setup.*

   **After Re-compiling Setup Program, you need to add following codes to the Pascal Script.**

   ```pascal
   [Files]
   Source: "InnoCallback.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

   [Code]
   #ifdef UNICODE
     #define AW "W"
   #else
     #define AW "A"
   #endif

   const
     GWL_WNDPROC = -4;
     SC_ABOUTBOX = 9999;
     SC_RESTORE = $F120;
     SC_MINIMIZE = $F020;
     WM_SYSCOMMAND = $0112;

   Type
     WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
     LPARAM = LongInt;
     LRESULT = LongInt;
     TWindowProc = function(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;

   var
     PrevWndProc: LongInt;

   function CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndFunc: LongInt; hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
     external 'CallWindowProc{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';
   function WrapWindowProc(Callback: TWindowProc; ParamCount: Integer): LongWord;
     external 'wrapcallback@files:InnoCallback.dll stdcall';
   function SetWindowLong(hWnd: HWND; nIndex: Integer; dwNewLong: LongInt): LongInt;
     external 'SetWindowLong{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';

   function Wizard_WMSYSCOMMAND(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
   begin
     if (uMsg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) and (wParam and $FFF0 = SC_MINIMIZE) then begin
       //SOMETHING LIKE BASS_Pause();.  
       Log('Wizard Window has been Minimized.'); 
     end;
     if (uMsg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) and (wParam and $FFF0 = SC_RESTORE) then begin
       //SOMETHING LIKE BASS_Start();. 
       Log('Wizard Window has been Restored.');
     end;
     if (uMsg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) and (wParam = SC_ABOUTBOX) then begin
       Result := 0;
       MainForm.ShowAboutBox;
     end
     else
       Result := CallWindowProc(PrevWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
   end;

   procedure InitializeWizard();
   begin
     PrevWndProc := SetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, WrapWindowProc(@Wizard_WMSYSCOMMAND, 4));
   end;

   procedure DeinitializeSetup();
   begin
     SetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, PrevWndProc);
   end;
   ```

   *Now, you should be notified immediately when WizardForm Minimizes or Restores via Compiler Log Messages. You can Pause or Resume Music according to your code by adding them in the function `Wizard_WMSYSCOMMAND`.*

Comment: Thinking hard is a most important way to find a solution. ;-)

Comment: In the `Wizard_WMSYSCOMMAND`, you should mask the `wParam` with `$FFF0`, the same way you do in the `TWizardForm.WMSysCommand`.

Comment: You mean like `(wParam = $FFF0 and SC_MINIMIZE)` ? If isn't it, how it sould be?

Comment: No `wParam  and $FFF0 = SC_MINIMIZE`

Comment: Is it right now? And I am not noticed anything special after changing it. Why it needs to be changed like you said?

Comment: Because the low 4-bits can be set to flags indicating a mechanism used to minimize/restore.

Comment: Okay, Do you tested this solution?

Comment: You (correctly) do the same in `TWizardForm.WMSysCommand` already!

Comment: Thank You!  This solution will be extremely useful to Inno Setup users who like Minimize and Restore Transitions and things related to these....... ;-)